# automatically apply bucket policy to all new uploaded files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So i have a bucket, set to private, with the following bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1565384592372",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1565384582998",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::324546464564:user/myself",
                    "arn:aws:iam::435345345345:user/a_colleague"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using an appleWatch to upload files to the bucket. The app calls my backend, where i generate a "signedURL" (from my secretKeys) and the app uses that url to push new files to the bucket.

Both me and my colleague have access to the bucket through the AWS console, are able to see the list of files, but when any of us try to download any of the files, we get Access denied:

```
<Error>
  <link type="text/css" id="dark-mode" rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
  <style type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"/>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>8EA4D71C48FDD48B</RequestId>
  <HostId>
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

So what do i have to do to make all new uploaded files, automatically available for the users(principals) that i specify in the bucket policy?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-owner-access/

Answer (score 0):

First, it's worth noting that a Bucket Policy is normally used to grant public access, or access to all users based upon a restriction, such as an IP address.

If you wish to grant bucket access permission to specific users, it is recommended to use an IAM Policy rather than a bucket policy. You can add a policy to your two IAM Users that gives them access to the bucket.

Based upon your description, the situation appears to be:

- An app is uploading files to an Amazon S3 bucket
- You are able to view the list of objects in the Amazon S3 management console
- However, you are not able to download the objects

This is possibly related to your policy. It is specifically granting access to:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
```

Some operations are performed on the **root** of the bucket, so you can instead try:

```
"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name", "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"]
```

If you do actually have the right Amazon S3 permissions, it might be related to the way that the files are uploaded. You can test this by uploading a file to the bucket yourself, then see whether you can download it. If you can download it, but not the files uploaded by the app, then you can **modify the way that the app uploads the files** by specifying:

```
"ACL": "bucket-owner-full-control"
```

I normally only see this in situations where credentials from one account are uploads files to a bucket owned by a different account. However, that doesn't sound like your situation.